# When I open my site, it doesn't open in the header, but in the footer or in the middle of the site

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

It's very strange behavior, I know, but when I go to my url to open my site, it doesn't open in the header but in the footer or middle of the site.

I need to scroll up Scrool to see the start menu.

The site is developed entirely in html with bootstrap.

[image: error]

Comment: Could you share some code? Also, just to make sure, what is the url at the top? Sometimes you'll have something like `#about` just meaning that you clicked on an anchor tag which points at an element on your site

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't work with hypotheticals much around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing happen when you follow your url with the id of section you want to scroll to, like: [www.yourwebsite.com#section2](http://www.yourwebsite.com#section2)

make sure that there is nothing addition in your url